# Password protect a swift app with Touch ID

Tags: swift, authentication, ios8, xcode6, touch-id

I am creating an app where a user can store other peoples information and I would like to allow users to protect the information stored in my app using a passcode or Touch ID (If their device supports it).

I have already got the Touch ID part working thanks to apple's documentation, but I am kind of stuck on how to implement the passcode lock. Will i have to create another view controller for that passcode-entry? How can I ensure that my app does not have access to users passcodes (in case the app gets hacked or run on a jailbroken device)? Does Apple provide a framework or library for this purpose?

Can someone point me to some source code or documentation I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this library, which looks very promising and its written in Swift from @yankodimitrov.
[SwiftPasscodeLock](https://github.com/yankodimitrov/SwiftPasscodeLock)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the sort of thing ibwas looking for!

Comment: What will be a nice addition to this library, will be an auto-expiry time frame . For example: if app goes to background and user opens the app within a minute don't ask for the passcode again. 
p.s: I might do a pull request soon for that type of functionality. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a library like [VENTouchLock](https://github.com/venmo/VENTouchLock)

Or you could look through its implementation and see how it works in order to replicate it.

Comment: is there a swift version?